# Group across two columns in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say in mongo I have a collection that looks like this:

```
+----+-----+-----+----------+
| id | x   | y   | quantity |
+----+-----+-----+----------+
| 1  | abc | jkl | 5        |
+----+-----+-----+----------+
| 2  | jkl | xyz | 10       |
+----+-----+-----+----------+
| 3  | xyz | abc | 20       |
+----+-----+-----+----------+
```

I want to do a $group where x equals y and sum up the quantity. So the output would look like:

```
+-----+-------+
| x   | total |
+-----+-------+
| abc | 25    |
+-----+-------+
| jkl | 15    |
+-----+-------+
| xyz | 30    |
+-----+-------+
```

Is this even possible to do in mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be performing a $group to retrieve the results. You're performing a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). This feature is new in MongoDB 3.2.

Using the sample data you provided, the aggregation would be the following:

```
db.join.aggregate( [
 { 
   "$lookup" : {
     "from" : "join",
     "localField" : "x", 
     "foreignField" : "y", 
     "as" : "matching_field"
   } 
 },
 {
   "$unwind" : "$matching_field"
 },
 {
   "$project" : {
     "_id" : 0,
     "x" : 1, 
     "total" : { "$sum" : [ "$quantity", "$matching_field.quantity"]}
   }
 }
])
```

The sample data set is pretty simple, so you'll need to test behavior when there are more than a simple result returned for a value, etc.

Edit:

It gets more complicated if there can be more than a single match between X and Y.

```
// Add document to return more than a single match for abc
db.join.insert( { "x" : "123", "y" : "abc", "quantity" : 100 })

// Had to add $group stage to consolidate matched results 
db.join.aggregate( [
  { 
    "$lookup" : {
      "from" : "join",
      "localField" : "x", 
      "foreignField" : "y", 
      "as" : "matching_field"
    } 
  },
  {
    "$unwind" : "$matching_field"
  },
  { "$group" : { 
    "_id" : { "x" : "$x", "quantity" : "$quantity" },
    "matched_quantities" : { "$sum" : "$matching_field.quantity" }
  }},
  {
    "$project" : {
      "x" : "$_id.x", 
      "total" : { "$sum" : [ "$_id.quantity", "$matched_quantities" ]}
    }
  }
])
```